# sum of interval values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Query:

```
select to_char(date, 'HH24:MI') as Timestamp,
count(case when type = 5 then 1 end) as Counts1,
count(case when type = 6 then 1 end) as Counts2,
from data
where date >= to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and date <= to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and type IN (5,6)
group by to_char(date, 'HH24:MI')
order by to_char(date, 'HH24:MI')
```

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Timestamp | Counts1   | Counts2  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 01:00     | 200       | 12       |
| 01:01     | 250       | 35       |
| 01:02     | 300       | 47       |
| 01:03     | 150       | 78       |
| 01:04     | 100       | 125      |
| 01:05     | 125       | 5        |
| 01:06     | 130       | 10       |
| 01:07     | 140       | 12       |
| 01:08     | 150       | 35       |
| 01:09     | 160       | 47       |
| 01:10     | 170       | 78       |
| 01:11     | 180       | 125      |
| 01:12     | 190       | 5        |
| 01:13     | 210       | 10       |
| 01:14     | 220       | 12       |
| 01:15     | 230       | 35       |
| 01:16     | 240       | 47       |
| 01:17     | 260       | 78       |
| 01:18     | 270       | 125      |
| 01:19     | 280       | 5        |
| 01:20     | 290       | 10       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

From above query we are getting result for every 1 minute, we are looking for data sum of every 5 minutes interval from given timestamp.

Expected result:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Timestamp | Counts1   | Counts2  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 01:05     | 1125      | 302      |
| 01:10     | 750       | 182      |
| 01:15     | 1030      | 187      |
| 01:20     | 1340      | 265      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Can some one help on this

Tried below:

```
select to_char(date + interval '5' minute, 'HH24:MI') as Timestamp,
count(case when type = 5 then 1 end) as Counts1,
count(case when type = 6 then 1 end) as Counts2,
from data
where date >= to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and date <= to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and type IN (5,6)
group by to_char(date + interval '5' minute, 'HH24:MI')
order by to_char(date + interval '5' minute, 'HH24:MI')
```

Below is the result we got:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Timestamp | Counts1   | Counts2  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 01:05     | 125       | 5        |
| 01:06     | 130       | 10       |
| 01:07     | 140       | 12       |
| 01:08     | 150       | 35       |
| 01:09     | 160       | 47       |
| 01:10     | 170       | 78       |
| 01:11     | 180       | 125      |
| 01:12     | 190       | 5        |
| 01:13     | 210       | 10       |
| 01:14     | 220       | 12       |
| 01:15     | 230       | 35       |
| 01:16     | 240       | 47       |
| 01:17     | 260       | 78       |
| 01:18     | 270       | 125      |
| 01:19     | 280       | 5        |
| 01:20     | 290       | 10       |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

We are looking for sum of every 5 minutes interval and expected result is below:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Timestamp | Counts1   | Counts2  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 01:05     | 1125      | 302      |
| 01:10     | 750       | 182      |
| 01:15     | 1030      | 187      |
| 01:20     | 1340      | 265      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: You could do "sum(counts1) over(order by rn rows between 4 preceding and 0 following)" and afterwards retain only the rows multiple of 5 min, the only problem is that the your first set is made of 6 rows instead of 5 because you include the ":00" row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CONNECT BY` to generate the periods:

```
WITH dat AS
(
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:00','HH24:MI') AS TIMESTAMP, 200 AS counts1, 12 AS counts2  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:01','HH24:MI'), 250, 35  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:02','HH24:MI'), 300, 47  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:03','HH24:MI'), 150, 78  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:04','HH24:MI'), 100, 125 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:05','HH24:MI'), 125, 5   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:06','HH24:MI'), 130, 10  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:07','HH24:MI'), 140, 12  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:08','HH24:MI'), 150, 35  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:09','HH24:MI'), 160, 47  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:10','HH24:MI'), 170, 78  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:11','HH24:MI'), 180, 125 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:12','HH24:MI'), 190, 5   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:13','HH24:MI'), 210, 10  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:14','HH24:MI'), 220, 12  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:15','HH24:MI'), 230, 35  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:16','HH24:MI'), 240, 47  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:17','HH24:MI'), 260, 78  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:18','HH24:MI'), 270, 125 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:19','HH24:MI'), 280, 5   FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  TO_DATE('01:20','HH24:MI'), 290, 10  FROM dual
)
SELECT periods.p_end, SUM(counts1), SUM(counts2)
  FROM dat times
     , (SELECT TO_DATE('01:00','HH24:MI') + (DECODE(LEVEL,1,1,2)-1)/(24*60) +  5*(LEVEL-1)/(24*60) AS p_start --start time + offset
             , TO_DATE('01:00','HH24:MI') + 5*(LEVEL)/(24*60) AS p_end 
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100 --adjust according to your data 
       ) periods
 WHERE times.TIMESTAMP >= periods.p_start 
   AND times.TIMESTAMP <= periods.p_end
 GROUP BY periods.p_end;
```

Probably not the optimal solution, but it gets the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select  '01:00' "TIMESTAMP", 200 "COUNTS1", 12 "COUNTS2" From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:01', 250, 35  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:02', 300, 47  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:03', 150, 78  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:04', 100, 125 From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:05', 125, 5   From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:06', 130, 10  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:07', 140, 12  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:08', 150, 35  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:09', 160, 47  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:10', 170, 78  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:11', 180, 125 From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:12', 190, 5   From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:13', 210, 10  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:14', 220, 12  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:15', 230, 35  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:16', 240, 47  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:17', 260, 78  From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:18', 270, 125 From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:19', 280, 5   From Dual Union All
            Select  '01:20', 290, 10  From Dual
        ),
```

... you could create CTE with steps of 5 minutes:

```sql
    grid AS
        (
            Select
                t.TIMESTAMP "TIMESTAMP",
                Min(s.STEP) "STEP"
            From 
                tbl t
            Inner Join
                ( Select LEVEL * 5 "STEP" From Dual d Connect By LEVEL <= 12  ) s ON(1 = 1)
            WHERE
                To_Number(SubStr(t.TIMESTAMP, 4, 2)) <= s.STEP
            GROUP BY
                t.TIMESTAMP
            Order By 
                t.TIMESTAMP
        )
```

... and join your data with the CTE, Group them by STEP and do the sum...

```sql
Select 
    SubStr(t.TIMESTAMP, 1, 3) || LPAD(STEP, 2, '0') "TIMESTAMP",
    Sum(t.COUNTS1) "SUM_1",
    Sum(t.COUNTS2) "SUM_2"
From 
    tbl t
INNER JOIN
    grid g ON(g.TIMESTAMP = t.TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY
    SubStr(t.TIMESTAMP, 1, 3) || LPAD(STEP, 2, '0')
ORDER BY
    SubStr(t.TIMESTAMP, 1, 3) || LPAD(STEP, 2, '0')
```

The result should be:

| TIMESTAMP | SUM_1 | SUM_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01:05 | 1125 | 302 |
| 01:10 | 750 | 182 |
| 01:15 | 1030 | 187 |
| 01:20 | 1340 | 265 |

And if you want to do it every 10 mins then just change the Inner Join part of CTE to look like this:

```sql
...
( Select LEVEL * 10 "STEP" From Dual d Connect By LEVEL <= 6 )
...
```

... in that case the result would be:

| TIMESTAMP | SUM_1 | SUM_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01:10 | 1875 | 484 |
| 01:20 | 2370 | 452 |

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Use [width_bucket](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/WIDTH_BUCKET.html) function to break into 5 minute intervals. Then, add the number of buckets multipled by the bucket size to the start interval. Need to subtract one from bucket number as first bucket will be bucket number 1.

```
select   to_char(to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')  -- interval start
                + (width_bucket(date
                               ,to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval start
                               ,to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval end
                               ,4 -- number of buckets 20/5 = 4 minutes
                               ) 
                   -1 -- for zero offset on first interval
                  )  
                  * 300/86400 -- to add 5 minute intervals to date
                ,'HH24:MI') timestamp, 
         count(case when type = 5 then 1 end) as Counts1,
         count(case when type = 6 then 1 end) as Counts2
from     data
where    date >= to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and      date <= to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and      type IN (5,6)
group by to_char(to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')  -- interval start
                + (width_bucket(date
                               ,to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval start
                               ,to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval end
                               ,4 -- number of buckets 20/5 = 4 minutes
                               ) 
                   -1 -- for zero offset on first interval
                  )  
                  * 300/86400 -- to add 5 minute intervals to date
                ,'HH24:MI')
order by 1
```

Can also achieve the same result without the function. No need to calculate number of buckets with this approach.

```
select to_char(to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval start
               + floor(
                        (date - to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')) -- date minus interval start
                        /(300/86400) -- divide into 5 minute intervals
                      ) -- gives interval number or bucket number
                      * 300/86400 -- multiply bucket number by bucket width
              ,'HH24:MI') timestamp, 
count(case when type = 5 then 1 end) as Counts1,
count(case when type = 6 then 1 end) as Counts2
from data
where date >= to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and date <= to_date('2022-10-27 01:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
and type IN (5,6)
group by to_char(to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- interval start
               + floor(
                        (date - to_date('2022-10-27 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')) -- date minus interval start
                        /(300/86400) -- divide into 5 minute intervals
                      ) -- gives interval number or bucket number
                      * 300/86400 -- multiply bucket number by bucket width
              ,'HH24:MI')
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


CREATE TABLE time_data (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt    DATE 
);

Generate a row for each minute in a day. This is my test data. I suspect you have plenty of data.

INSERT INTO time_data(dt)
select timestamp '2022-11-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(rownum-1*1,'MINUTE')
    from dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (24*60);
 

Group into 5 minute intervals. Your data should show different counts.

select  trunc(dt,'hh24') + numtodsinterval(floor(to_char(dt,'mi') / 5) * 5,'minute') dt_5_min,
        count(*) cnt
  from  time_data
  group by trunc(dt,'hh24') + numtodsinterval(floor(to_char(dt,'mi') / 5) * 5,'minute')
  order by trunc(dt,'hh24') + numtodsinterval(floor(to_char(dt,'mi') / 5) * 5,'minute')
/
```